# Verify field value for each list item in a REST response

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Let's say that we have the following json response:

```
{
   "data":
       [
       {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Pablo"
       },
       {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Ernesto"
       }
       ]
       ...
}
```

Where the data list could consist of many more objects. If I where to verify that no name field is set to null, what would be the Rest Assured way of doing this?

Now I'm using:

```
from(response.asString()).get("data");
```

to get a list of HashMaps, and then moving on from there for each entry. But I guess there is some other way that is more efficient?

Edit/Clarification: I am wondering if there is a way to do this without the creation of a list of maps?

Comment: can you share how you are getting a list of HashMaps ?

Comment: import static com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.from and use from as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so perhaps I should have read the docs a bit more carefully, the easiest (and intended) way to retrieve e.g. all name values (as in my example) is to use JsonPath like so:

```
List<Object> names = from(response.asString()).get("data.name");
```

So there are no magical utility methods within the Rest-Assured library to do this except using JsonPath.from().get() and then to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

i guess this is the best we can do

```
List<HashMap> data = from(response.asString()).get("data");
for(HashMap map: data){
    if(map.get("name") == null){
        // null name found
    }
}
// No null name found
```